# Are Git commits from a long deleted (> a year ago) branch permanently lost or can they be recovered?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am tasked with picking up and continuing with an incomplete feature that was developed over a year ago by a colleague that is no longer with our company. I have discovered that he did a fair bit of work on this that I would like to use rather than starting again from scratch. I have found the following.

1. The Jira ticket shows that there is a declined pull request.
2. I have found the declined [WIP] pull request in Bitbucket, but the branch it was based on no longer exists, presumably deleted during a cleanup of old branches.
3. Jira shows me that there were six commits (see screenshot) but I have not been able to find them by searching the local repo (with gitk) for either the SHAs or commit descriptions.
4. I have also tried searching for the SHAs in all branches on the Bitbucket Commits page but am told that no commits match.

It appears that only some history showing these commits existed remains but I'm hoping there may be some way to retrieve the commits themselves. Can anyone suggest further actions I might try?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click on one of the shown commit hashes?

Comment: It's possible that someone in your company checked out that branch (e.g. for reviewing it) and still have it locally on their machine.

Comment: @Donat it gets 404

Answer (score 0):

You can ask co-workers if someone has the commit and could push it.

If the branch has been deleted in all co-workers local repositories, chance are the commits has been garbage collected long ago because the reflog last only 3 months by default.

Maybe if you find a co-worker that has not touched its repository for months and the garbage collection has not been run.

But if a PR has been made and/or if the details of the commits in bitbucket are still visible (click on one to see the diff details), it should mean that the commits are still on the server. **In this case, your best luck is maybe calling the Bitbucket Api to create a branch on the existing but not fetchable/reachable commit** like that:

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{repo_slug}/src/ --F "parents={parent_hash}" --F "branch={branch_name}"
```

Taken from :
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-discussions/Create-branch-BitBucket-REST-API-Support/td-p/610927#M94

PS: to do the curl call you will surely have to pass some credentials or token but that's out of scope of the answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask my colleagues tomorrow but I'm not sure how lucky I'll be. We've had quite a bit of staff turnover in the last year. All members of the author's team have left, as have all but one of those that would have been default PR reviewers at the time, so I'm not very hopeful.

Comment: @SteveCrane yes, that's what I think in such circumstances that's why I said that maybe the Api solution is your best option? Do you see the commit details in bitbucket ?

Comment: I don't think even the API solution will help. The Bitbucket PR page shows that the branch was deleted and that it couldn't load commits. Jira shows the commits with the commit SHAs as links to Bitbucket but clicking them gets 404.

Comment: @SteveCrane Yes, it seems that the commits have been garbage collected on the server. So your chances to find them are very low... Good luck!